# Checkbox in a DataGridView column is not getting checked sometimes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, checkbox, datagridview

I use this code to check all the check-boxes in a data grid view in VB.NET ([2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) - [.NET Framework 4.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4)),

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To (DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
    DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True
Next
```

Sometimes when one of the row is selected (not checked but just the entire row is selected) while this code is running, it checks all other check-boxes in the column except the selected one. What is wrong here?

I also try adding this code,

```
DataGridView.SelectedCells(0).Cells(0).Value = True
```

Did not work.

Comment: I have had this problem. The value of the cell is changed in the datasource, but the cell isn't checked on the GUI. If you click off of it, it will change to checked. I usually get around it by setting the selected cell to nothing, i.e. deselecting.

Comment: A good idea. Do you know any code that can automatically deselect the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, the issue is that the box is checked in the datasource, but the GUI hasn't refreshed that cell to reflect it. If you click off of it, the cell should change/refresh to your new value. After you have made your data changes, at the very end you should deselect cells/rows. You can do it by:

```
 Datagridview.ClearSelection()
```

or

```
 Datagridview.CurrentCell = Nothing 'deselects
```

You get the idea. This is what has worked for me in the past.

Comment: This worded, `Datagridview.CurrentCell = Nothing`.